# Drush policy restriction doesn't restrict sql_sync

Tags: drush, staging

On my @dev machine, I've installed a drush policy rule that should (?) prevent sql_sync to my remote @prod machine,

```
cat /etc/drush/policy.drush.inc
    <?php
    function drush_policy_sql_sync_validate($source = NULL, $destination = NULL) { 
        if ($destination == '@prod') {
            return drush_set_error(dt('POLICY: sql_sync TO @prod is NOT allowed')) 
        }
    }
```

When I attempt the sql_sync, instead of preventing the action and printing the error, it allows it,

```
drush -v sql-sync --simulate=0 @dev @prod
    Loaded alias @defaults from file /etc/drush/aliases.drushrc.php                                [notice]
    Loaded alias @prod from file /etc/drush/aliases.drushrc.php                                    [notice]
    Loaded alias @dev from file /etc/drush/aliases.drushrc.php                                     [notice]
    /home/drupal/drush/drush  --backend=2 --verbose --uri=https://dev.mydomain.com                 [notice]
    --root=/home/drupal/dev  sql-conf   --all 2>&1
    ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@prod.mydomain.com 'drush  --backend=2 --verbose          [notice]
    --uri=https://prod.mydomain.com --root=/home/drupal/prod  sql-conf   --all
    2>&1' 2>&1
    Modification time of local dump file /home/drupal/drush-dumps/sql-sync-dev.sql is less than 24 hours [warning]
    old. Use the --no-cache option to force a refresh.

    You will destroy data in prod.mydomain.com/prodDB and replace with data from devDB.

    You might want to make a backup first, using the sql-dump command.

    Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
    Calling system(rsync -e 'ssh ' -akzv --exclude=".git" --exclude=".gitignore" --exclude=".hg" --exclude=".hgignore" --exclude=".hgrags" --exclude=".bzr" --exclude=".bzrignore" --exclude=".bzrtags" --exclude=".svn" --stats --progress /home/drupal/drush-dumps/sql-sync-dev.sql root@prod.mydomain.com:/home/drupal/drush-dumps/sql-sync-prod.sql);
    sending incremental file list

    Number of files: 1
    Number of files transferred: 0
    Total file size: 14634184 bytes
    Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
    Literal data: 0 bytes
    Matched data: 0 bytes
    File list size: 37
    File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
    File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
    Total bytes sent: 46
    Total bytes received: 12

    sent 46 bytes  received 12 bytes  38.67 bytes/sec
    total size is 14634184  speedup is 252313.52
    Calling system(ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no root@prod.mydomain.com 'mysql --database=prodDB --host=127.0.0.1 --user=dbadmin --password=secretpassword --silent < /home/drupal/drush-dumps/sql-sync-prod.sql 2>&1');
    Command dispatch complete                                                                      [notice]
```

What do I need to change/add to get the policy to restrict the sql_sync?

Comment: It looks like you may have accidentally created a new user. I suggest registering the account you asked the question as, and logging in with that. If you use the @MidGes account, then you can comment on your own question / answers.

Answer (score 3):

I added this to my sync_enable commandfile, and it definitely worked:

```
function drush_sync_enable_sql_sync_validate($source = NULL, $destination = NULL) {
  if (strpos($destination, 'live')) {
    return drush_set_error('DRUSH_BAD_DEVOPS_NO_BISCUIT', dt("Don't sync to live."));
  }
}
```

That looks the same as what you've got, so the next thing I'd recommend that you try is `drush cc drush`, to clear the Drush commandfile cache.  That will insure that Drush can see your policy file.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, the problem was that Drush looks for site-wide commandfiles in '/usr/share/drush/commands', not '/etc/drush'.  Move your policy file there, and then `drush cc drush`, and it should work.